# Redis client list showing clients idle for 27 days

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I recently ran the client list command on my redis server, which is used by node_redis, and saw that there are clients which have been connected for over 27 days.

My server has restarted many times before that, been down for maintenance and we've had new deployments, but how are these clients still connected?

Is it safe to set a client idle timeout to 30 min and let these clients die?

edit: we are not doing any pub/sub